# Docker-Compose logs time based

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, containers

Hi I am stuck with an issue. I check docker-compose logs by command 'docker-compose logs -f'. However, if my container had started 5 days back it would start printing logs from the time container was started. I want that logs should generate for only 24 hours.
What change can I do in docker-compose.yml file to configure this.

I dont want to use some different command other than docker-compose logs -f. I want to make configuration in a way where default logs on docker-compose logs -f are last 24 hour logs. Please guide. Any help would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_logs/):

> --since           Show logs since timestamp (e.g. 2013-01-02T13:23:37Z) or relative (e.g. 42m for 42 minutes)

To show the last 24h of your docker compose logs use `--since` option e.g.

```bash
docker compose logs --since 24h -f
```

Comment: Basically I dont want to use this option I want that I configure logs in a way where I get default 24 hour logs when I dont docker-compose logs -f

Comment: more over this command isnt working either @sebastian

Comment: If you want the result of `docker compose logs --since 24h -f` without specifiying `--since`  by running `docker compose logs -f`, I think you're out of luck. Why not use a bash alias or a shell script? What do you mean it isn't working?